# Change the size of the background image codewise from a label in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In the app that I am making I have some background images for some labels.
The image is 500x550 pixels but my label is 250x275 pixels.
How can I make the code change the width and height of the background so it **fits** the size of the label?

Code I have now:

```
lblMainNumber.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "image.png")!)
```

Comment: patternImage biggest use case is Tiled images, and shouldn't really be used for this. I agree with Earls answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to have a container UIView with size of 250 x 275 that will contain 2 subviews with same size:

1) a UIImageView with your image (set its contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit)

2) UILabel with your text. It will be on top of the UIImageView to stay visible.

You would possibly want to set both subviews (via autolayout) to match the size of container view.
Pattern image approach is pain in the ass and not wort the effort.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl and come back to thank you if it worked ^^